# How to edit a variable name into in a javascript command (.innerHTML)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I need to execute the following command   `$("#title").html( choice#  + " wins! ");` but instead of "#", it should be an integer and that should trigger variables I have stored called `choice1` - `choice10` are variables hence when the code is executed, the string stored in `choice1` - `choice10` (depending on what is chosen) should show on the innerHTML.

So far I tried `$("#title").html( "choice" + position + " wins! ");` where `var position;` is a random number and it changes the html to literally "choice3 wins! " (or whatever number it was) instead of printing the string in `var choice3;`.

Comment: If it is a global variable, you can try `window['choice'+ position]` for the value of that variable

Comment: Instead of doing all that just use an array `var choices = ['choise one', 'choise two', ..]` and then you can use `choices[position]`

Comment: @Taplar No it's inside an event listener function...

Comment: @Titus No because each choice (string) is assigned a value which will be shown on the website and the highest value wins...

Comment: That is not a reason not to use an array.

Comment: Oh I get what you mean thanks!!! Let me try if it would work